# Validation failure results in nil variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a variable `@products = Product.all` defined inside new method in a controller. It contains values from a db table to be shown in a select box on form.

When the create method raise validation errors I am calling `render :action => 'new'`.

All the other variables seem to come back fine, but @products comes back as nil

What am I missing here.

Comment: `@products` or `@product`? You've got both here; do you have both in your code as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`render :action => new` is asking `ActionView` to render the *view* for the `new` action -- it does not run the `new` action in the current controller, as you may expect.

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render:

> Using `render` with `:action` is a frequent source of confusion for Rails newcomers. The specified action is used to determine which view to render, but Rails does not run any of the code for that action in the controller. Any instance variables that you require in the view must be set up in the current action before calling `render`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `render :action => :new`, you could use `redirect_to :action => :new`. This will load up all instance variables correctly, and not force you to copy the entire `new` logic in your `create` action.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`render :action => 'new'` only renders a view and does not call new method in the controller. So any variables that were instantiated in new method will have to be instantiated right before calling `render :action  => 'new'`